# What is the rigorous way to study changes of a shape under continuous maps.

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am a graduate student working on a small research project in computer science. I want to study how the shape of a manifold (say, smooth or piecewise smooth manifold) changes under a certain type of maps (please, see the example).

I am familiar with introductory level topology (homology, a bit of Morse theory, some differential topology), but I could not identify the rigorous mathematical context or framework in which to study my problem. **So my question is what subfield of topology I should look at to study this type of problems?** Below is a description of what I want to study.

---

Broadly speaking, I want to understand how the shape of object changes under "simple" continuous transformations. To be more specific, I would like, for example, to understand or being able to say something on how the Betti numbers change under continuous transformations.

For example, considers two concentric squares in the figure below. The squares are a single "piecewise" smooth manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Betti numbers $\beta_0 = 2, \beta_1 = 2$, the manifold is mapped under the continuous transformation $(x,y) \mapsto (f(x), g(y))$ where

$$f(x) := \begin{cases}(1 - x^2)  & x \in [-1,1], \\ 0 & other\,. \end{cases} \quad g(y) := y ~~~~(\textit{identity}).$$

[image]

The resulting manifold has different shape (on the right of the figure), while the original manifold had Betti numbers $\beta_0 = 2, \beta_1 = 2$, the the resulting manifold has $\beta_0 = 2, \beta_1 = 0$. What can I say in general situations, how difficult is this problem to study, what specific name can I call my continuous transformation (beyond just calling it a continuous embedding)?

Hope my question is not too vague, any comments are welcome.